# PlasticSCM: Deep compare on pending changes

Tags: plasticscm

I am using PSCM6. I have 2 usecase problems (same solution) :

- 1.)
  after updating server+client from V5 to V6 all my repositories are "dirty" - i.e. all files are listed in "pending changes". When I double-click a file PSCM shows "files are identical".
- 2.)
  I have a Linux server which does not send the file time via FTP for some reason. I have a day-date but no time with minutes and seconds. When I transfer files from that server, my FTP client discards the date and sets the file date to the current time. Thus, all files are listed in "pending changes" again. On other servers I have to set a time-shift due to different time-zones. If I forget that, I have the same problem - the files are marked as changed.

**My question:**

**Is it possible to run a deep scan for changes on all files which have been detected as being changed.** Just comparing the date and giving no option for further change detection feels a bit clumsy to me - even if it is theoretically correct - because 2 files with the same content but different time stamps might be correctly treated as different files. But from a programmer point of view they are identical.

These are my "pending changes options" settings:

[image]

Comment: Plastic SCM has a preference to "Check content (hash) when the file timestamp is modified to set it as changed". Doesn't it help?

Comment: @CarlosAlbaZamanillo - I have added a screenshot of the settings - where can I find the one you are mentioning? Many thanks!

Comment: The preference is not in the "Pending Changes" view options. But it the GUI --> Prefereces --> Other options.

Comment: Thank you @CarlosAlbaZamanillo - it works great - even with good performance! Do you want to create an answer, so that I can mark it as solved?

Comment: Sure. Let me post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plastic SCM has a preference to "Check content (hash) when the file timestamp is modified to set it as changed".
The preference is not in the "Pending Changes" view options. 
But in the GUI --> Preferences --> Other options.

Comment: I now have "check content" active, but still get "files identical". The reason is that I have set to ignore White spaces in comparison. Obviously this setting conflicts with the "check content" setting (it's ignored).